# Get Simple Eating GET Parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm upgrading a website to [GetSimple 3.3](http://get-simple.info/) and having some issues with rewrite rules in .htaccess.

My current .htaccess will take urls such as

```
http://www.example.com/page/
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/parent/page/
```

and rewrite them to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=page
```

When I try to add some GET parameters to the URL like so, it completely removes them

```
http://www.example.com/page/?key=value
```

I would like it to change to this

```
http://www.ecample.com/index.php?id=page&key=value
```

Here is my .htaccess rules for URLs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Usually RewriteBase is just '/', but 
    # replace it with your subdirectory path
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The `QSA` should append the query string, are you *sure* they're still getting removed?

Comment: Yes. They are removed from the URL and the don't show up when I do a var_dump of $_GET. Only the id parameter is there.

Comment: I think it may be something else then, because [those rules work perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WgKzL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jon pointed out, the .htaccess file is fine. Get Simple was checking the URL and resubmitted it if it didn't like the format. I commented out the GSCANONICAL flag in gsconfig.php and it's now working.